# MPI send matrix columns (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, mpi, send

I tried to send the second and third column of a matrix from the processes with rank one and two with MPI to the process with rank zero.

On the internet I found this example http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node70.htm#Figure4 and wrote a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int id;
    int matrix[3][3];
    int matrixB[9];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            if(id == 0)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            else
                matrix[i][j] = j+1;

    MPI_Datatype matrixSpalte;

    MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 3, MPI_INT, &matrixSpalte);
    MPI_Type_commit(&matrixSpalte);

    MPI_Gather(&matrix[0][id], 1, matrixSpalte, &matrixB[0], 1, matrixSpalte, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(id == 0)
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
            if(i % 3 == 0)          
                cout << endl;

            cout << matrixB[i] << " (" << i << ") ";

        }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

but the output is:

```
0 (0) 0 (1) 1351992736 (2)
0 (3) 254423040 (4) 1 (5)
0 (6) 2 (7) 1351992752 (8)
```

It should be:

```
1 (0) 2 (1) 3 (2)
1 (3) 2 (4) 3 (5)
1 (6) 2 (7) 3 (8)
```

and I have not idea why this isn't working. I hope someone can help me to find the mistake in my code.

Your sincerely,

Heinz

Solution (thx to Jonathan Dursi):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int id;
    int matrix[3][3];
    int matrixB[9];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            if(id == 0)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            else
                matrix[i][j] = j+1;

    MPI_Datatype matrixSpalte, tmp;

    MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 3, MPI_INT, &tmp);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp, 0, sizeof(int), &matrixSpalte);  // !!!
    MPI_Type_commit(&matrixSpalte);

    MPI_Gather(&matrix[0][id], 1, matrixSpalte, matrixB, 1, matrixSpalte, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(id == 0)
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
            if(i % 3 == 0)          
                cout << endl;

            cout << matrixB[i] << " (" << i << ") ";

        }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to resize the vector type to use it in a gather like this - eg, `MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 3, MPI_INT, &tmp); MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp, 0, sizeof(int), &matrixSpalte); MPI_Type_commit(&matrixSpalte);`.  For an explanation of why, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi/9271753#9271753).

Comment: If you do actually have the solution, you should answer your own question and mark it accordingly instead of putting the answer in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`MPI_Gather` should be passed a buffer that can store all the elements in a contiguous array. Take a look at [the picture here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node70.htm#Node70)

That is `rbuf` must point to an array of 9 `int`s. This is why you are getting the `Abort trap: 6` error as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431147/abort-trap-6-error-in-c). You are trying to write in `matrix[0][3]` through `matrix[0][8]`

Also, your `recv_type` must be `MPI_INT`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the receive datatype to an one dimensional array. But this sadly did not solved the whole problem. (I wrote the new output and source code in the initial post)

Comment: Yeah, forgot one more thing. Updated my answer.