# Abort trap: 6 error in C

Tags: c, loops, pointers

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned long hash(char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *str++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
int main()
{

    char s[50],ans[50];

    int max_freq = 0,num=0,hash_value,i;
    unsigned long int a[10000],b[10000];


    FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/Brikman23/Desktop/input.txt","r"); //remember to specify correct path of input file..

    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Input File not found..");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",s)==1)
    {
        hash_value = hash(s);
        for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        if(a[i]==hash_value)
        break;

        if(i==num)
        {
            b[num]=1;
            a[num]=hash_value;

            if(b[num]>max_freq)
            {
                max_freq = b[num];
                strcpy(ans,s);

            }   

            num++;  
        }
        else
        {
            b[i]++;
            if(b[i]>max_freq)
            {
                max_freq = b[i];
                strcpy(ans,s);

            }   

        }   


    }

    printf("The word with the highest number of appearances is: %s",ans);
    printf("\nNumber of appearances: %d",max_freq);

    return 0;

}
```

when I compile this with gcc, it does not give me an error but the output always gives me Abort trap:6 when instead it should be giving me:

The word with the highest number of appearances is:

Number of appearances:

I have looked at other posts but they have not been of help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431147/abort-trap-6-error-in-c) from you too? The answer's accepted. The question does look similar but not the code

Comment: @Eregrith That isn't the same.

Comment: nope, that post is not mine....

Comment: any ideas to why I am getting this error?

Comment: Do you make sure the code is never fed a line of more then 49 `char`s long? Better change `fscanf(fp,"%s",s)==1` to be `fscanf(fp,"%49s",s)==1`.

Comment: how would you initialize it? ...I am unsure

Comment: You got it ALK! The output is now correct! Thank you!

Comment: @Brikman23 only if the lines do not differ after the 49th char.

Comment: @Brikman23, and only if the most frequently occuring value is shorter than 50 chars.

Comment: the does not actually cleanly compile.  there are at least 3 warnings that need fixed.  the most obvious problems are the 3 comparisons between signed and unsigned values

Comment: there are (at least) 3 magic numbers in the code .. 50, 10000, and 5381.  The should be #defined name (value)   where value is 50, 10000, and 5381.  where name is a meaningful name that indicates what the number means, in the context of the code.

Comment: regarding the line: 'while(fscanf(fp,"%s",s)==1)'  there is nothing limiting the length of the string being read.  Therefore buffer overflow can occur.  This would be undefined behaviour, possibly leading to a seg fault event.   suggest placing a length modifier in the '%s' input/conversion specifier.

Comment: these three lines: '        for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        if(a[i]==hash_value)
        break;'   is difficult for us humans to read for several reasons, 1) braces would help clarify the code, 2) indentation would help clarify the code.

Comment: variable names should be meaningful, in the context where they are being used.  'a', 'b', 's' are not meaningful variable names.  I,.E. they give no indication of what they contain nor their intended usage.

Comment: the posted code has a bug, wherein if more than one word has the same number of appearances, then the code only displays the first word encountered with that number of appearances.    Note: I'm running Linux ubuntu 14.04 and the code ran fine (however, I did not have any words over 49 characters long