# Initializing a multidimensional array: {0} versus {{{0}}}

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

In the C code I am analyzing, there are a lot of multidimensional (struct) arrays which are initialized with a different number of curly brackets e.g. `{{0}}` or `{{{0}}}`.

However, replacing these by `{0}` also works perfectly.

Is there a (functional) difference between using one or more sets of curly brackets (`{}`) occurrences ?

Comment: [Initializing entire 2D array with one value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520880/initializing-entire-2d-array-with-one-value) should answer why `{0}` works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no functional difference. The C standard allows to leave out intermediate `{}`. In particular, the form `{ 0 }` is an initializer that can be used for all data types.

Answer (score 8):

You have two choices: either `{ 0 }`, which works for any aggregate or union type and zero initializes every member, or using the correct form which must correspond to all members correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Just to reiterate what Jens has already said, `{0}` works for any type. It is the "universal zero initializer" in C.
See C11 draft, [6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).

So, to initialize a 3D array either `{0}` or `{{{0}}}` can be used. Personally I'd use `{0}` as it's easier to type and read and works for every type. That means, the following are all valid initializations:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = {0,};
    int *p = {0,};
    int *q = {0};
    int arr[3][3][3][3] = {0};
}
```

More importantly, if you happen to have some unknown/opaque type, for example from a third-party libraries, then the only portable way
to initialize them is using `{0}`. Any other way of zero-ing it (such as using `memset()` or directly `some_type_t state = 0;`) would require some internal knowledge of the type involved and risks being non-portable.

Comment: If you have an opaque type from another library, you shouldn't meddle with its internals in the first place, but let that library initialize it.